# how to know all file names of the images from whole website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get all images of my whole website in an array, and all of my images are in a folder called **images** and within that folder many subfolders are there, So now how can I get all the images' path in an array?

Is it possible just with jquery, javascript? If not, php is ok.

Comment: Is this a one time thing? What kind of server do you have?

Comment: apache server...... and why needed to know about the server??? And yes I would like to take whole images in an array.... like var imgArr = [all images here]

Answer (score 0):

try this PHP Script:

```
$dir = "images/*/";

//get all files with .jpg
$images = glob("" . $dir . "*.jpg");

$imgs = array();
// store images in $imgs - after that optional display
foreach($images as $image) {
    $imgs[] = $image;
}

//display
foreach ($imgs as $img) {
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" />';
}
```

to store in a JS array:

```
$JSarray = json_encode($imgs);
echo "var JSarray = ". $JSarray . ";\n";
```

Comment: there might be nother kind of extension for images , so just jpg is not enough solution...

Comment: and I wanted to store all the images into an array.... do stuff with js... thanks though for answering...

Comment: `glob("" . $dir . "*.{gif,jpg,png}");` try this then

Comment: I would like to store the images in an array (javascript), so how can I take from php and store in js array?

Comment: then I can use JSarray in my js??

Answer (score 0):

I found this **recursive** function that can give you the tree of a given directory, you can use the $exclude param to filter only image files

```
<?php
/**
     * Get an array that represents directory tree
     * @param string $directory     Directory path
     * @param bool $recursive         Include sub directories
     * @param bool $listDirs         Include directories on listing
     * @param bool $listFiles         Include files on listing
     * @param regex $exclude         Exclude paths that matches this regex
     */
    function directoryToArray($directory, $recursive = true, $listDirs = false, $listFiles = true, $exclude = '') {
        $arrayItems = array();
        $skipByExclude = false;
        $handle = opendir($directory);
        if ($handle) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            preg_match("/(^(([\.]){1,2})$|(\.(svn|git|md))|(Thumbs\.db|\.DS_STORE))$/iu", $file, $skip);
            if($exclude){
                preg_match($exclude, $file, $skipByExclude);
            }
            if (!$skip && !$skipByExclude) {
                if (is_dir($directory. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file)) {
                    if($recursive) {
                        $arrayItems = array_merge($arrayItems, directoryToArray($directory. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file, $recursive, $listDirs, $listFiles, $exclude));
                    }
                    if($listDirs){
                        $file = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
                        $arrayItems[] = $file;
                    }
                } else {
                    if($listFiles){
                        $file = $directory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
                        $arrayItems[] = $file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
        }
        return $arrayItems;
    }
?>
```

[source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#109140)

And about the jQuery way, you can't access to the directory directly, you have to provide the list with an ajax call to your backend and give a json object so you render it with jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Use [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) , [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) and [`RegexIterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.regexiterator.php) to achieve this .

```
$imagesExtensions = array('jpg','png','gif'); //<=-- Add your extensions
$extensions = implode('|',$imagesExtensions);
$directory  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('images');
$iterator   = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);//RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$regex      = new RegexIterator($iterator, "/^.+\.$extensions$/i", RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
foreach ($regex as $filename=>$object) {
    echo $filename . '<br>';
    $images[] = $filename; //<----- All images are stored in this array sequentially
}
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
images\google\client\ext\resources\themes\images\access\boundlist\trigger-arrow.png
images\google\client\ext\resources\themes\images\access\box\corners-blue.gif
images\google\client\ext\resources\themes\images\access\box\corners.gif
//....... Goes on..
```